# Magento Soap api get all products sku, names, short description and image

Tags: api, magento, product, categories, magento-1.9

My code is working fine but take so much time for show result because i have above 1500 products.

So any one modify my code or best way to show results

```
$results = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId);

$productData = new stdClass();
$productData->additional_attributes = array('short_description','cost'); 


foreach($results as $value){
    $results_product = $proxy->catalogProductInfo($sessionId,$value->product_id,null,$productData);
    $pro_imag = $proxy->catalogProductAttributeMediaList($sessionId, $value->product_id);
    echo "";
    echo "".$sno++."".$value->product_id."".$value->sku."".$value->name."".$results_product->additional_attributes[0]->value."".abs($results_product->additional_attributes[1]->value)."".abs($results_product->price)." url."' width='80px' height='80px'> ";
    echo "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code and use magento site for easy api examples like following, example SOAP V2 (Complex Filter)

```
<?php 
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'type',
            'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => 'simple,configurable')
        )
    )
);
$result = $client->catalogProductList($session, $complexFilter);

var_dump ($result);
```

Comment: but short_descrition not in catalogProductList.

Comment: issue is catalogProductInfo not support product_id (array)

Comment: I just new to API. How to to run soap v2, i have created soap user and role and my code -> https://snag.gy/FKm36D.jpg and my file bala.php available in my root folder. How can i run in URL? @Dave